# Does a header file also get uploaded into the micro-controller with the program?

Tags: arduino, embedded

By including a library file in the program, such as `LiquidCrystal.h` while programming Arduino, there are certain functions that were declared in the library. So while uploading the program to the micro-controller, does the header file also get uploaded?

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags, Arduino is not C. 2) Your question is answered instantly you undertstand what a header file is. For a start: it is **not** a library.

Comment: The answer is: No, the header file does not get uploaded. Its purpose is to provide the compiler with references to code that exists elsewhere – not just in a library, but in another program compilation unit.

Comment: So how microcontroller knows what to do when the library function executes?

Comment: The microcontroller has no idea about libraries (neither has the CPU in you PC, smartphone or any other CPU of the last ca. 30 years (and almost all before that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answers can be found in a books. OP should read and learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The source code is *compiled*, each separate compilation unit is *linked* to each other and to the libraries to generate a machine-code binary, which is what is loaded to the processor.

Compiled languages, such as C and C++ are not executed directly like *interpreted* languages.  Instead the compiler generates target-native *machine code*, which the processor can run directly.

Whilst the compiler deals with individual source files (to generate *object code*, these may include references to code in other modules and libraries - these references are resolved by the linker, which replaces the symbolic links with direct memory addresses.  The resulting binary is what is executed.

Header files are just source code generally containing *declarations* of function signatures for code contained in other modules or libraries.  These allow the compiler to "know" what these interfaces "look like" without having needing to know the implementation details (which the linker resolves).

More complete description available [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-embedded-systems/0596009836/ch04.html) (for example)

All this happens, even in the Arduino environment - in that case a lot of the detail is hidden from you, which is what makes Arduino a simple environment for beginners, but ultimately far less flexible - you relinquish some control and visibility in exchange for not being scared off embedded development as "just too hard".  All the steps however are visible in the build output log text if you care to look.

Specific build process details for Arduino are described [here](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/sketch-build-process/).

Comment: Thank You so  much for the help.